# Flashcards and tasks

Tags: tasks, flashcards

I use the flashcard package in my work. I want to use `task` package in my `flashcards`, but it seems to be impossible. Who can help me?

My TeX code is:

```
\documentclass[avery5371,grid,frame]{flashcards}
\usepackage{tasks}
\begin{document}
%\cardfrontstyle{empty}
\begin{flashcard}{Hi}
\begin{tasks}(4)
\task First
\task Second
\task Third
\task Forth
\end{tasks}
\end{flashcard}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where the problem stems from but I have a simple solution: wrap the `tasks` environment in braces:

```
\documentclass[avery5371,grid,frame]{flashcards}
\usepackage{tasks}
\begin{document}

\begin{flashcard}{Hi}
  {\begin{tasks}(4)
    \task First
    \task Second
    \task Third
    \task Forth
  \end{tasks}}
\end{flashcard}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the issue. The compilation never ends, I don't understand why. Do you absolutely need the `task` package? You could use the `enumitem` environment and customize it, as shown below.

**Alternative solution**

```
\documentclass[avery5371,grid,frame]{flashcards}

%\usepackage{tasks}% Doesn't work
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

    \begin{flashcard}{Hi}

        Toto

        \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
            \item First
            \item Second
            \item Third
            \item Forth
        \end{enumerate}

    \end{flashcard}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This package has been used for multiple-choice questions. If it can not possible I should use another enviroments, like you.